# How to delete e-mail messages from the Deleted Items folder using CFIMAP or CFPOP

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to delete e-mail messages from the Deleted Items folder using CFIMAP or CFPOP

```
<cfpop action="delete" server="#mymailserver#" port="995" secure="yes" 
    username="#myusername#" password="#mypassword#" 
    uid="#uid#" >
```

or

```
<cfimap action="open" server="#mymailserver#" port="993" 
    secure="yes" connection="imapconnection" 
    username="#myusername#" password="#mypassword#" >

<cfimap action="delete" uid="#id#" connection="imapconnection">

<cfimap action="close" connection = "imapconnection">
```

where #id# is a UID of a message in the Deleted Items folder.

When I use CFPOP, it has no effect.  Further investigation has shown that I cannot delete messages with CFPOP regardless of what folder they are in.  Getting this to work with CFPOP is not of great concern to me because I can delete messages in folders other than the Deleted Items folder using CFIMAP.

When I use CFIMAP to delete a message from the Deleted Items folder, I get a java NullPointerException error.  As stated above, I have no trouble deleting messages in other folders, such as the Inbox or Sent Items folder.

Is there a way to remove e-mail messages from the Deleted Items folder, either one at a time or all at one time?

Comment: Well, I did find out that I can delete all the messages in the Deleted Items folder by just using <CFIMAP action="delete" folder="#myfolder#" connection="imapconnection">

Comment: The null pointer exception suggests that your `id` variable might be incorrect.

Comment: The ID is definitely correct.  When I use Inspect Element on the web-mail client for the server and e-mail address, it confirms the ID that I previously downloaded using CFIMAP with GetAll.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting the message, include the folder and the UID.

```
<cfimap action="delete" folder="#myfolder#" uid="#id#" connection="imapconnection">
```